# DevTools shows up often in the middle of coding in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

somebody please!

The following picture often a lots during coding in Jupyter Notebook. Could you please tell me a way how to fix this?

Thank you in advance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3k65b.png)

Answer (score 0):

I got this. This is just a devloper tools issue from chrome browser. If anyone faced this issue and got stuck in it, feel free to ask me.